# pandas calculate 3 months cummulative sum on monthly basis at each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I am trying to calculate cumsum for last 3 months for each row level. So, my main data frame looks like this

| ID | Month | Level_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AUG_15 | 1 |
| 1 | SEP_15 | 0 |
| 1 | OCT_15 | 1 |
| 1 | NOV_15 | 1 |
| 1 | DEC_15 | 0 |
| 1 | JAN_16 | 1 |
| 1 | FEB_16 | 1 |
| 1 | MAR_16 | 1 |
| 2 | AUG_15 | 1 |
| 2 | SEP_15 | 1 |
| 2 | OCT_15 | 1 |
| 2 | NOV_15 | 1 |
| 2 | DEC_15 | 1 |
| 2 | JAN_16 | 1 |
| 2 | FEB_16 | 1 |
| 2 | MAR_16 | 1 |

and my resultant desired output is

| ID | Month | Level_1 | Level_1_m3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AUG_15 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | SEP_15 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | OCT_15 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | NOV_15 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | DEC_15 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | JAN_16 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | FEB_16 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | MAR_16 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | AUG_15 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | SEP_15 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | OCT_15 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | NOV_15 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | DEC_15 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | JAN_16 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | FEB_16 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | MAR_16 | 1 | 3 |

so, basically the m3 columns looks at last three months from a particular and calculate cumsum.
e.g. for Id 1 and month Mar_16, cumsum value is 3 as it is calculated using values of Mar_16, Feb_16 and Jan_16.

Is there are builtin method that can help achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, someone did posted an answer(got removed later) that I should explore pandas rolling method and it did the job.

Here is my current solution:-

```
df.groupby('ID')['Level_1'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using shift, if your data is already sorted

```
df["Level_1_m3"]=df["Level_1"]+df["Level_1"].shift(1).fillna(0)+df["Level_1"].shift(2).fillna(0)
```